# Unable to fetch data from sqlite using timestamp column

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite

I have a table in sqlite which has column of timestamp datatype. Now I want to fetch data based on timestamp from table. The format is "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"

`Select * from table where ts<'2013-10-08 04:30:00'`

returns all the data and doesn't return data specific to the time that I have mentioned.

Is there any specific way to query the table using timestamp column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your query definitely right? You're asking for everything *before* a certain time *today*. If you have any amount of historical data, that's probably pretty much everything.

Comment: @shambulator, the query is correct and same is the behaviour when I use the date other than current date.

Answer (score 0):

The query you have is correct, it should return you the correct result I suggest you check the data in table.

Have done a test in SQL Fiddle and is working check link below:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/75cae/2

My table contains:

```
'2013-01-07 04:30:00'
'2013-01-20 05:30:00'
'2012-12-30 04:30:00'
```

and my query is :

```
   SELECT * FROM t
   WHERE dt > '2013-01-07 05:30:00'
```

Which returns me :

```
  2013-01-20 05:30:00
```

***EDIT::***

As per you comment changed the format : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1b6f8/2

```
'2013-01-07 04:30PM'
'2013-01-20 05:30PM'
'2012-12-30 04:30AM'
```

The Query:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE dt > '2013-01-07 04:30:00'
```

OR:

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE dt > '2013-01-07 04:29PM'
```

The result:

```
2013-01-07 04:30PM
2013-01-20 05:30PM
```

Comment: Hi Sam, the data in the table is in this format '8/10/2013 4:45 PM' even when I insert it in this format '2013-08-10 16:45:55'. Could this be the reason why it is not getting the data? This is my insert query: INSERT INTO table (ts) VALUES ('2013-08-10 16:45:55');

Comment: @user1140366 see my edit changed the format and still returns me the correct values..using 2 queries

Comment: The format you are using is different. Data in my table is in this format: '8/10/2013 4:45 PM'